# Как сделать пустое действие при обработке исключения в Python?

Tags: python

Добрый день! Есть такой вопрос: при обработке исключения в Python хочу сделать пустое действие, приходится делать `print('')`, но немного не устраивает. Подскажите, как такое сделать?

Comment: Для этого есть `pass` )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как написали в комменте к вопросу, для этого существует ключевое слово pass. Используется оно в том случае, если нужно сделать у чего-либо пустое тело, например, у функции:

```
def my_func():
  pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Либо если при обработке исключения - 
    try:
        pass
    except IOError as e:
        print(e)

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    # --------
    # проверяйте в этом блоке свой код на исключения
    # --------
except Exception:  # при любом возникшем исключении код продолжит просто работать дальше:
    pass
```

Comment: `except: pass` игнорирует *все* исключения. Подобную конструкцию лучше почти никогда не использовать. Вместо этого можно игнорировать исключения, подходящие к ситуации (например, `try: os.remove('some_file') \n except OSError: pass`) или же если хочется перехватывать исключения без разбору, то можно использовать `except Exception`, которое по меньшей мере пропускает  `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit` (что желательно, как правило). Если есть *абсолютная* уверенность, что `except:` необходим в каком-то изолированном случае, то для отладки можно `logging.exception('bare except')` использовать.

Comment: Насчет того, что на практике лучше перебирать исключения по типам - согласен. Но я просто ответил на тот вопрос, что задавался - при любом исключении продолжнить работу. Насчет того, что будет корректнее использовать  `except Exception` вместо `exception` - согласен полностью. Поэтому исправил)